# How can I simulate Hibernate errors during an automated unit or system test?

Tags: hibernate, testing, seam

I'm trying to test my code, written using JBoss Seam and Hibernate. What I'd like to achieve is this:

Execute a SeamTest automated test to run a particular method on a Seam component. This component performs a database update (merge or save). I'd like to cause this update to fail, allowing me to test my error-handling code and ensuring my code recovers gracefully.

I've not been able to determine a simple way of doing this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the update fail because of a (simulated) malfunction in Hibernate or because your entity-validation did not succeed? I claim you hardly run into the former case. I never experienced Hibernate problems that weren't caused by my code. For such situations, you have to make sure that your transaction is rolled backed if a Hibernate exception occurs. Normally, if you have annotated your action method in Seam with `@Transactional` your transaction should be rolled back upon a `RuntimeException` (each `HibernateException` is a `RuntimeException`).

For the latter case (testing your entity-validation) you can create a `ComponentTest` that sends an invalid entity to your update method.

Another situation you could check is what happens if you call your method with a `null` entity to be updated or with an entity that doesn't exist on the DB.

If you post the code of your update method, I'll try to give some more suggestions.

Comment: I wasn't specifically thinking of which type of exception I was trying to test, so your message has provided me with a way forward, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used Seam.

Assuming one unit test is one transaction, wouldn't throwing a RuntimeException after a database update be enough?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Seam, but I have used DbUnit on a Hibernate project.

DbUnit works with JUnit, and allows the following:

- load data into the DB
- execute a JUnit test (which may query the DB)
- remove said data from the DB

There are other variations, based on configuration.

With this background, your test could load in a record with a value in a unique column. The test then tries to save the same value. Now, you have an error condition in a repeatable, controlled test, and without modifying the project code.

Comment: Using DBUnit is definitely on my todo list, so I'll save this solution for when I implement that. Thanks for replying!